# User-space swap on mmap()-ped files

Tags: swap, mmap

Imagine a system with very small ram (nearly embedded). It is enough - for nearly all tasks, but with an exception. There is a task X, which requires a huge amount of RAM what the machine has not.

Imagine that also swap is impossible (it is a low-ram VM, where the host provider forbids swap).

I think, we could

- create a large file
- mmap()-ing it
- "asking" (reconfiguring) `malloc()` in the glibc to use this `mmap()`-ed area, instead the physical RAM.

*What we would effectively have, is a userspace-level swap functionality, for only a single process.*

As far I know, the malloc() implementation of the glibc is not a very well configurable one, but

- there are also other `malloc()` implementations
- and not even the glibc malloc is very crap, only deep-level play is uncommon with it.

Would it be possible? Does any, or similar solution exist for that?

Comment: Now I can see in `strace` outputs, that `malloc()` works with anonymous `mmap()` calls, at least for large allocations. Thus, such a tool could be easily developed by hooking `mmap()`, too.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to do something like this. You'll need one file per process to implement this easily. Obviously, you'll be limited by the disk space in the VM. Performance will also not be great since the kernel will periodically flush the memory to disk. This can be mitigated by using some sysctl tunables (search for linux periodic write back).

Then you have to plug this into `malloc` one of the other. With glibc, there is the `__morecore()` hook (look at glibc's `malloc.h`) that can you use to replace `sbrk()`. That will not catch *all* glibc allocations since under some circumstances, glibc calls `mmap()` directly instead of `__morecore()`. This can tweaked using `mallopt()`. You can also use a LD_PRELOAD library to catch the `mmap()` calls. But this is not completely trivial to get right.